# Limit of tan function

Tags: limits, trigonometry

This is a question from an old tutorial for a basic mathematical analysis module.

Show that $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\tan^n(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{n}) = e^2$$

My tutor has already gone through this in class but I am still confused. Is there anything wrong with the following reasoning?

Since $\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{n} \to \frac{\pi}{4}$ as $n \to \infty$,

it seems to me that $\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{n}) \to \tan(\frac{\pi}{4}) = {1}$,

and hence $\tan^n(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{n}) \to 1^n = 1$.

Additionally, my tutor has given a hint, to use Squeeze theorem along with the definition $e = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty }(1 + {1\over n})^n$, but I can't see how these are to be used.

Edit: Here's another attempt I've made.

After using addition formula for tangent, we get

$$\frac{1 + \tan{\frac{1}{n}}}{1- \tan{\frac{1}{n}}} = 1 - \frac{2\tan{\frac{1}{n}}}{1-\tan{\frac{1}{n}}} = 1 - \frac{1}{\frac{1-\tan{\frac{1}{n}}}{2\tan{\frac{1}{n}}}} = [(1 - \frac{1}{\frac{1-\tan{\frac{1}{n}}}{2\tan{\frac{1}{n}}}})^\frac{1}{\frac{1-\tan{\frac{1}{n}}}{2\tan{\frac{1}{n}}}}]^\frac{2\tan{\frac{1}{n}}}{1-\tan{\frac{1}{n}}}$$

so given that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{\frac{\tan{\frac{1}{n}}}{\frac{1}{n}}}=1$, we have

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\tan^n(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{n}) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}[(1 - \frac{1}{\frac{1-\tan{\frac{1}{n}}}{2\tan{\frac{1}{n}}}})^\frac{1}{\frac{1-\tan{\frac{1}{n}}}{2\tan{\frac{1}{n}}}}]^\frac{2n\tan{\frac{1}{n}}}{1-\tan{\frac{1}{n}}} = e^\frac{2*1}{1-0} = e^2$$

I'm really hoping that this method works as well! So sorry for the ugly formatting, I couldn't figure out some parts.

Comment: The 'hence' statement is flawed reasoning. If that reasoning was valid, then $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ would not be $e$.

Comment: @JustinBenfield that makes a lot of sense. I really should have seen that myself, so thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: The counterexample is obvious once you look at it, but the underlying reasons that that intuition is, in fact, wrong, is not at all obvious. One way to see why that naive intuition is flawed is to consider how $\tan^n$ diverges as $n\rightarrow\infty$ for any input slightly above $\frac{\pi}{4}$ (so the $\frac{1}{n}$ is basically 'racing' towards $0$ as the $\tan^n$ is 'racing' towards $\infty$, and the actual outcome is really controlled by the relationship between them).

Comment: You need the identity for $\tan(x+y) $ and $\tan \frac{1}{n}\sim\frac{1}{n}$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: The challenge with applying the Squeeze Theorem is to find the right bounding sequences. What you want to do is construct two sequences that both converge to $e^2$ for which it is easy to show that one of them bounds the given sequence below, and the other bounds it above. One of them can be the product of the sequence for $e$ with itself, since given _convergent_ sequences, $a_n,b_n$, with limits (as $n\rightarrow\infty$ of $L,K$ respectively), that the limit (as $n\rightarrow\infty$) of the sequence $a_n\cdot b_n=L\cdot K$.

Comment: I think I somewhat see the way to use the definition of e now!

$$\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{\tan{\frac{\pi}{4}} + \tan{\frac{1}{n}}}{1-\tan\frac{\pi}{4}\tan{\frac{1}{n}}} = \frac{1+\tan{\frac{1}{n}}}{1-\tan{\frac{1}{n}}}$$ 

and further simplification gets the expression into a form that is similar to $(1+\frac{1}{n})$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the addition angle formula for the tangent function we can write

$$\tan^n\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac1n\right)=\left(\frac{1+\tan\left(\frac1n\right)}{1-\tan\left(\frac1n\right)}\right)^n$$

Note that $\tan(x)=x+O(x^3)$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1+\tan\left(\frac1n\right)}{1-\tan\left(\frac1n\right)}\right)^n&=\left(\frac{1+\frac1n +O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)}{1-\frac1n +O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)}\right)^n\\\\
&=\left(\frac{1+\frac1n }{1-\frac1n }\right)^n\left(\frac{1+\frac{O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)}{1+\frac1n}}{1 +\frac{O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)}{1-\frac1n }}\right)^n\\\\
&\to \frac {e}{e^{-1}}\,\frac{1}{1}\,\,\text{as}\,\,n\to \infty\\\\
&=e^2
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: You may want to explain how you achieved the separation of taylor series into the first two terms versus the rest in the step before you took the limit, nice answer!

Comment: @JustinBenfield Thank you!  Much appreciative.  The terms of interest were simply factored out of the numerator and denominator terms.  Does that make sense?  -Mark

Comment: I understood it, but it took me a bit to see how. I have a new question though: How do you know that limit of the error terms is $\frac{1}{1}$ or that the limit of that product is the product of those limits (this is true iff you know _a priori_ that both sequences converge)?

Comment: We can certainly write the product under the limit.  Then we can see that the limits of the constituent terms do indeed have the limits as reported.  To see that the "error" terms approach $1$, we can use a number of approaches.  An easy one is to write $(1+O(n^{-3}))^n=e^{n\log(1+O(n^{-3}))}$ and note that $n\log(1+O(n^{-3}))\to 0$ since $\log(1+O(n^{-3}))=O(n^{-3})$.

Comment: I'm not yet convinced of the last equality, but I buy the rest of that.

Comment: Do you know that $\frac{x}{x+1}\le \log(1+x)\le x$?  Let $x=O(n^{-3})$ and we have $\log(1+O(n^{-3}))=O(n^{-3})$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38611/discussion-between-justin-benfield-and-dr-mv).

Comment: @Dr.MV thanks for replying! Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with big O notation, but I will read up and try to understand.

Comment: @JustinBenfield I have edited my question to include a second attempt at proving the limit. Could I ask you both to help me see if it checks out?

Comment: @Jessica I'm not sure where you're getting that exponent from, but the rest looks good, going from the rewrite of $\tan$ to rewriting $\tan^n$ would just mean putting an $n$ as exponent on everything that is replacing the original $\tan$.

Answer (score 0):

If the only standard limit available is $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} = e$$ then we are out of luck here. It is better to assume the following standard limits $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan x}{x} = 1 = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + x)}{x}$$ and then we can easily evaluate the desired limit. We have
\begin{align}
\log L &= \log\left\{\lim_{n \to \infty}\tan^{n}\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{1}{n}\right)\right\}\notag\\
&= \log\left\{\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{1 + \tan(1/n)}{1 - \tan(1/n)}\right)^{n}\right\}\notag\\
&= \log\left\{\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{2\tan(1/n)}{1 - \tan(1/n)}\right)^{n}\right\}\notag\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\log\left(1 + \frac{2\tan(1/n)}{1 - \tan(1/n)}\right)^{n}\text{ (via continuity of log)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}n\log\left(1 + \frac{2\tan(1/n)}{1 - \tan(1/n)}\right)\notag\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}n\cdot\dfrac{2\tan(1/n)}{1 - \tan(1/n)}\cdot\dfrac{\log\left(1 + \dfrac{2\tan(1/n)}{1 - \tan(1/n)}\right)}{\dfrac{2\tan(1/n)}{1 - \tan(1/n)}}\notag\\
&= 2\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{\tan(1/n)}{1/n}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1 - \tan(1/n)}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\log\left(1 + x\right)}{x}\notag\\
&= 2\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\notag\\
&= 2\notag
\end{align}
Hence $L = e^{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

Applying $\textbf{L'Hospital's Rule}$, we have $$\begin{align*}\lim_{x \to +\infty} \left[x\ln \tan \left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\right]&=\lim_{x \to +\infty}\dfrac{\ln \tan \left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{x}}\\&=\lim_{x \to +\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\cos \left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)}\\&=\lim_{x \to +\infty}\dfrac{2}{ \sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\dfrac{2}{x}\right)}\\&=\lim_{x \to +\infty}\dfrac{2}{ \cos\left(\dfrac{2}{x}\right)}\\&=2. \end{align*}$$ Hence, $$\begin{align*}\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\tan^n\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{n}\right)&=\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}\tan^x\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{x}\right)\\&=\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} \exp\left[x\ln \tan \left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\right]\\&=\exp\left[\lim_{x \to \infty}x\ln \tan \left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\right]\\&=\mathbb{e}^2.\end{align*}$$

Comment: The question you are answering  is $2$ years old and already has an accepted answer. Instead of this, you could focus your knowledge on currently open and active questions.There are many new questions and it would be much appreciated if you answered them instead.

Comment: Not a good way to farm "Revival" and "Necromancer" badges because this question is not popular enough.